# Unable to make JNI call from c++ to java in android lollipop using jni

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, android-5.0-lollipop

I am making a library app which detects native crashes in android using google breakpad. Whenever my main app has a native crash, breakpad invokes the following callback.
From this callback, I need to call a static void method in a java class using JNI.

```
bool breakpad_callback(const google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor& descriptor, void* context, bool succeeded) {

JNIEnv* env = NULL;

if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
{
    if(isDebug)
        LOGI("Failed to get the environment");
    return false;
}

if(isDebug)
    LOGI("attaching thread ...");
vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

if(isDebug)
    LOGI("handle exception");

 ExceptionHandlerClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("com/abc/Myclass"));
        if (ExceptionHandlerClass == NULL)
            LOGE("Could not find java class");

 ExceptionHandlerMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(ExceptionHandlerClass, "handleException", "()V");
        if (ExceptionHandlerMethod == NULL)
            LOGE("Could not bind exception handler method");

// handle exception
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(ExceptionHandlerClass, ExceptionHandlerMethod);

if(env->ExceptionCheck()) {
    LOGI("got exception");
    env->ExceptionDescribe();       
}


if(isDebug)
    LOGI("exception handled");
}
```

This is my java method:

```
package com.abc;
public class Myclass {
  public static void handleException() {
     System.out.println("inside handle exception");
  }
}
```

This used to work fine before Android 5.0. But in Lollipop, I am not able to call my java method as I am not able to see 'inside handle exception' log on Logcat console.

Here are the log msgs I see on logcat:

```
12-01 13:57:46.617: I/AACRNative(1617): attaching thread ...
12-01 13:57:46.617: I/AACRNative(1617): handle exception
12-01 13:57:46.619: I/AACRNative(1617): got exception
12-01 13:57:46.620: W/art(1617): JNI WARNING: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown while calling printStackTrace
12-01 13:57:46.620: I/AACRNative(1617): exception handled
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Do you see any output? Do any of the LOGE lines show up in the logcat? Also, you should also check in your code if any java exceptions have been thrown. My guess would be a `ClassNotFoundException`. In lollipop the java VM is changed from `dalvik` to `ART`. `ART` is sticter when it comes to class names. Make sure yours is correct.

Comment: Hi, I have added some log statements in my code. You were right as I am getting exception after calling java method but I am not able to print exception using ExceptionDescribe();
Also verified my class name. It seems to be correct.

Comment: It's not a given that your native crash handling code is going to find the VM in a state that can be called into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=162663), it mentions some workaround, but haven't been fixed yet. ART uses an alternate stack for signal handling, that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread in the 'breakpad_callback' method and then make JNI call in the thread.It will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
JNI WARNING: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown while calling printStackTrace
```

Your app consume too much stack.